# jQuery: Is it possible to test for both input type and and attribute in one selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of `input` elements and using one selector I want to find those that

1. are checkboxes
2. have the `value` attribute set

Can I do that?

I tried:

- `$(items).find("input:checkbox[value]")`
- `$(items).find("input[value]:checkbox")`

But both ignore the `[value]` and only test for `input:checkbox`.

Sure, I can use two selectors, but just one would be nicer.

---

My essential use case is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cfQLU/).

Basically, I want to take some action on a checkbox based on whether other checkboxes are unchecked or not. In this example the "parent" checkbox is still checked because the jQuery selector `"input[value]:checkbox"` in function `getChildrenCheckboxes` matches the "No Child" checkbox as well as the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, if people take the time to provide you with answers, you could at least take the effort in **accepting those answers**.

Secondly, regarding your question you can either use  `filter()` or check whether value is empty:

```
$('input[value!=""]:checkbox').addClass('selected');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/pEK3c/

**or**

```
$('input:checkbox').filter(function(){
 return this.value.length;   
}).addClass('selected');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/duAB8/

**edit**

Regarding the question why not just use `$('input[value]')` to check the presence of a `value`, firstly it depends whether you want to know whether its empty, or not there at all, and secondly, and perhaps most importantly, do you want it to work consistently over different browsers?

The following markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="" />
<input type="checkbox"  />
<input type="checkbox" value="23" title="a" />
```

With the following selector:

```
$('input:[value]:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
```

Will give the following results:

```
Chrome 11, X - - X
FF4,       X - X X
IE 8,      X - X X
```

So are you interested in knowing whether the attribute is defined, or whether its empty? If the first one, you can expect differentiating results for that selector. Where as the 2 first examples both give consistent results for `X - - X`.

It'd be quite a different story if you'd be looking for the `[title]` attribute...

Comment: If I read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) correctly I can check for just the existence of an attribute. My tests indicate the same. As for accepting answers: I feel awfully bad about that myself, but so far I somehow always did something else than any of the respondents proposed and I did not think it right to accept an answer just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Legate My answer to that was too long to explain in the comments here, so I updated my answer explaining the problems of using just that [value] selector.

Comment: @Niklas: There's something really weird with those selectors, that's for sure. ;-) Just take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qQua6/1/). The checkbox is unchecked in both Chrome 12 and FF 3.6, even though there is no value attribute.

Comment: @Legate but it **does** have a value, you've defined them as *true* / *on* with the checked="checked". What would the form return if you'd submit a form with checkboxes that are ticked, but no value defined? What kind of situation are you trying to apply these to?

Comment: @Niklas: I added my essential use case to my question. But I guess you already provided the answer: `value` is set even if the **attribute** `value` is not, but `checked` is. And yes, I'll accept your answer if you confirm. ;-)

Comment: @legate If you are just interested whether a checkbox is ticked or not, use the `:checked` selector instead and don't go through the rocky problems of the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

If you want elements that are checkboxes AND have the value attribute, you can leverage the multiple attribute selector: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][value]")
```

Comment: The does an OR, not an AND as the OP wants.

Comment: See my answer explaining the problems of using `[value]`

Comment: @Niklas, thanks for pointing that out. +1. I think the filter looks like the best way.